# Fire click event twice in react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-typescript

I'm trying to test if a button toggle works as expected.

This is my code.

```
<>
  <IconButton color="secondary" data-testid="HelpIconButton" ref={anchorRef} onClick={handleToggle}>
    <Help />
  </IconButton>
  <Popper {...{ open }} anchorEl={anchorRef.current} transition disablePortal data-testid="HelpIconPopper">
    {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
      <Grow {...TransitionProps} style={{ transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom' }}>
        <Paper>
          <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
            <MenuList autoFocusItem={open} onKeyDown={handleListKeyDown}>
              {menuItems.map(({ onClick, label }, index) => (
                <MenuItem key={index} {...{ onClick }}>
                  {label}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </MenuList>
          </ClickAwayListener>
        </Paper>
      </Grow>
    )}
  </Popper>
</>
```

In the browser, clicking the browser works as expected. Clicking on the `IconButton` toggles the `Popper`, removing and adding it into the DOM.
On test however, firing a click event placed the `Popper` in the DOM but its not removed when fired again. Hence, the popper isn't toggled.

Here is the test Code.

```
it('Ensures the help menu toggles when the help button is clicked.', () => {
  const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<HelpButton />);
  expect(queryByTestId('HelpIconPopper')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('HelpIconButton'));
  expect(queryByTestId('HelpIconPopper')).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('HelpIconButton'));
  expect(queryByTestId('HelpIconPopper')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

A work around currently in use is using `fireEvent.doubleClick`

```
it('Ensures the help menu toggles when the help button is clicked.', () => {
  const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<HelpButton />);
  expect(queryByTestId('HelpIconPopper')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.doubleClick(getByTestId('HelpIconButton'));
  expect(queryByTestId('HelpIconPopper')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The second test passes.

Comment: Sometimes you need to wait for the UI to update. https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#async

Comment: I think [`waitForElementToBeRemoved`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitforelementtoberemoved) worked for me. Thanks.